# Transpose a single row multiple columns into multiple rows single colum

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table valued function in sql server which returns multiple rows and single column such as below

```
1
2
3
```

I use the syntax `select * from dbo.function` to use the values returned by this function in **where clause** of my queries.

Now apart from the value returned by the function I want to put certain hard coded values in that **where clause**.

For example :

```
Select * from dbo.table where ID in (Select * from dbo.function + **I want to add some more values here**)
```

So that if function returns

```
1
2
3
```

I want to add lets say

```
4
5
```

in that list such that final query becomes as follows :

```
select * from dbo.table where ID in (1,2,3,4,5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `or`:

```
Select *
from dbo.table
where ID in (Select * from dbo.function) or
      ID in (4, 5)
```

Although you could mangle the subquery using `union all`, the above makes the query easier to follow (in my opinion).  Also, in the event that "function" is really a table, it is easier for the optimizer to recognize appropriate indexes.